# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPrivate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a model I created using mongoose findByIdAndUpdate method. However I keep getting the error that the model of the attribute I am trying to change is undefined. below is the code.

**Here's my sketch schema**

```
//create new schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//sketch schema with 2 fields
const sketchSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: 'sketch.js' },
    isPrivate: {type: Boolean, default: true }
}, {
    timestamps: true, //this means it automatically let you know when it was created and modified
})

//create a model from the user schema def to use it
const Sketch = mongoose.model('Sketch', sketchSchema);

module.exports = Sketch;
```

**My API code**

```
router.route("/sketches/:id").put((req, res) => {

  //find sketch by id and ONLY update privacy field

  Sketch.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
      {
       $set: {isPrivate: req.body.isPrivate}
  },{
      new: true
  })
  .then(sketch => {
      sketch.save()
      .then(() => res.json(sketch))
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
})
```

**Here is my server app code**

```
//create instances of express and CORS
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//this
require('dotenv').config()

//create server app
const app = express();
//what is this line saying
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


const sketchRouter = require('./routes');
app.use('/exercises', sketchRouter);

//Middleware 
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//mongoDB database set up
const uri  = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true}) 
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB DB est. successfully")
})


//Start the server
app.listen(port, () => { 
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

I am using postman to test this put request for a specific sketch by its object id, and passing in the body of the request to change the sketch's IsPrivate field from true to false

**Image of req body using postman here**

[postman put request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp6ZS.png)

Comment: did you use bodyParser in your app?

Comment: No I didn't, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Your `req.body` is undefined. Have you attempted to check the value or `req` or `req.body`? Without more data I can't say why it's undefined... but it is.

Comment: Using the postman service , I assumed I made the body having a object with a key value property  "isPrivate" : "true", see image above. Also, what data should I add to help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out why I was getting the undefined error message. It was due to my misordering of the code: specifically, configuring the routes file to be used BEFORE the app's main middleware. Essentially, all of the API functions weren't JSON enabled.